# How do I draw a badge on my Dock icon using Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, badge, nsdocktile

How do I add a badge to the Dock icon for my app using Cocoa? Is there any roughly "standardized" way to do this?

(I'm referring to the kind of badges that show up in Mail, iChat etc. to indicate the number of unread messages and the like.)

Cocoa Touch does provide one such method, but I haven't been able to find any equivalent for a regular Cocoa application.

Comment: Great resource is also WWDC 2003 Session 424 - Cocoa: Tips and Tricks https://youtu.be/Y3jYF0EhxOg?t=1099

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use

```
 [[[NSApplication sharedApplication] dockTile] setBadgeLabel:@"2234"];
```

This method, and the `NSDockTile` class, has been available since Leopard.

Comment: Here is the same thing in **Swift 4**: `NSApplication.shared.dockTile.badgeLabel = "123"`

Answer (score 25):

It should be noted that NSDockTile is only available on Leopard. If you need to target Tiger you'll need to use `-setApplicationIconImage:` on your NSApplication object and draw your badge by hand.

Also, it's not in the documentation outside of the release notes that I could find but you get your application's dock tile by sending the `dockTile` message to your NSApplication object.

```
NSDockTile *tile = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] dockTile];
[tile setBadgeLabel:@"Lots"];
```

Comment: Realistically, with 10.6 coming out in the next 6 months or less, only supporting Leopard is probably just fine.

Comment: In yours and my case maybe so, but Debajit should at least be aware of the implications of using NSDockTile and the other available options.

Answer (score 17):

A quick google search turned up the [NSDockTile](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/NSDockTile_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. Seems pretty self-explanatory once you take a gander at the documentation.