# Remove single notification from notification center iOS

Tags: ios, notifications

I want to implement same notification feature in my app just like in-built Mail application of iOS devices?

In Mail application single notification get removed out of many from notification center when user view it?

I have searched for same and got answer for removing all notifications by using

`[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;`

But I don't want to remove all at once, I want to implement it same as in-built Mail application. Can anybody help on this?

Comment: Calling
`[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber -= 1` when you want to decrease badges does not work ?

Comment: take a look here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861131/updating-ios-badge-without-push-notifications

Comment: I know about the badge count decrement but I want to remove one by one notification from notification center.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = MAX([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber - 1, 0);
```