# backgroundTaskIdentifier - UIAlert doesn't popup when app is closed

Tags: swift

I'm using backgroundTaskIdentifier to get the stopwatch to continue when the app is closed.  The counter updates fine when the app is closed.

But I would like to receive my popup alert notification when the app is closed. Right now it pops up when I open the app but that doesnt help me because the timer has already stopped.

Related question. Can an app have push notifications if nothing is being pushed from a server? I mean can I badge my app when the timer is complete?

Variable declaration

```
var backgroundTaskIdentifier: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier?
```

ViewDidLoad

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "updateTimerBasedViews", name: Timer.notificationSecondTick, object: timer)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "timerComplete", name: Timer.notificationComplete, object: timer)

backgroundTaskIdentifier = UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler({
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTaskIdentifier!)
    })
```

Applicable functions

```
func updateTimerBasedViews() {
    updateTimerLabel()
    updateProgressView()
}

func timerComplete() {
    switchToPickerView()
    playAlarm()
    // TO DO : ADD UIAlert

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: "Time to do it!", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

    //self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil) // old

    presentViewController(alert, animated: true) { () -> Void in
        let localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
        localNotification.alertAction = "Testing"
        localNotification.alertBody = "Hello World!"
        localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
    }
```

AppDelegate

```
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Sound, .Alert, .Badge], categories: nil))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show popup not in your application but on your device background task with showing `UIAlertAction` is not right way. It will show bubble in your application context, not the os system.

Your approach should be in using [local notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html)

You should realize smth like this:

```
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings (forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Alert, categories: nil))

var localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
localNotification.alertAction = "Testing"
localNotification.alertBody = "Hello World!"
localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

You can find a lot of tutorial, like [this](http://thecodeninja.tumblr.com/post/89942124085/notifications-in-ios-8-part-1-using-swift-what)

Comment: Thanks. I will mark as correct. You are getting close to 1000 :) I just realized I needed to distinguish between app, local and push notifications. Will this give me a red badge and a alert popup even if the app is closed? Can I put this in the same function above? I thought many people put this code in AppDelegate? Also should I choose between OS or app popup? Having both is not good right? If the app is open it doesn't make sense to have a local notification.

Comment: I think, that you should experiment with this, I mean, as I understand you want to send local notifications after the background task is completed. Maybe you should call `registerUserNotificationSettings` not in background task. But it looks like the right way to solve your problem

Comment: put this code `application.registerUserNotificationSettings` in didFinishLaunching and the other code in you background task completion handler

Comment: It works. I'm getting local notifications but not a badge or sound, only the banner. I have edited my code to show you. What do I need to do? Oh one thing. I'm getting this warning. `Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged`.

Comment: read answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861131/updating-ios-badge-without-push-notifications (add `localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1`)

Comment: your warning - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890761/warning-presenting-view-controllers-on-detached-view-controllers-is-discourage (first of all try to google it - practically everything is well known and you can get answer quickly by yourself)