# Reset or clear iOS app badge without any app interactions like open the app or push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Any possibility to reset/clear app badge without any app interactions such as opening the app or any push/local notifications. My need is, I want to reset my app badge starting off every day without even opening the app or with any notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can schedule local notification for end of day with badge count equal 0. Check this out [Updating iOS badge without push notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861131/updating-ios-badge-without-push-notifications)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with the help of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861131/updating-ios-badge-without-push-notifications). The working code is:

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
NSCalendarUnit unitDay = NSCalendarUnitDay;
localNotification.repeatInterval = unitDay;
localNotification.fireDate = fireDate;
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = -1;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Local notification has no `alertBody`, so local notification will not display upfront.
If need to show `alertBody` then add `localNotification.alertBody = @"Your notification alertBody";`.

Thanks for the answer.